90° film wrapping on cylinder
I am trying to animate a film which get wrapped around a cylindric bar in a 90° direction. At my first approach I did this by manipulate the alpha channel of the material.
(see the attached gif).
Does anyone has a smart idea how to animate this by mesh or curve manipulation? Especially the curved shape seems to be the tricky part.
Thanks for any kind of advice.




I'm not sure I understand what you did at first: "manipulate the alpha channel of the material"? How is this supposed to wrap the film around the bar?

have you tried with a Curve modifier?

First I modeled the complete tape strip, with helix curves around the bar and converted that to mesh. Afterwards I animated the mapping of the material to get the illusion of movement of the tape.

Yes, I did some attempt with the curve modifier, but didn't get the right result. If you wind the tape along a curve the shape will not fit to the cylinder surface.

@Blendamed , what are you talking about? Of course it will. You can control Tilt for each curve point(Sidebar).

I know, but the tilt rotation works only on one axis, and I didn't manage to get the tape properly wrapped around the cylinder bar.

I also did some experiments with the build modifier. It worked, but than the tape needs a 45° angle shape to get a good looking result.  But the tape should hit the bar with its 90° cutting edge in a 45° direction.

yes not easy to do it with a Curve modifier, the ribbon gets badly deformed, if you managed to do it with a texture, why don't you stick with it?

This can be done rather easily in Geometry Nodes:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Using a minimal setup, first spawn half of a circle around origin, spanning from 0° to 180°: Blender uses mathematical coordinates so this means filling two top quadrants, therefore in the next frame extruding "down" (working in 2D coordinates at this point), in third frame convert back to curve to trim it to taste and this is also where you animate, either by keyframing "Start" or "End" or by calculating them based on "Scene Time" node:

Imgur mirror
Within the same frame capture the x position so that after beveling the curve on following frame, all points of a beveled segment share the stored "x". This way, when skewing, the side stays perpendicular to the main surface. Mute the "Capture Attribute" node to see the difference:

Imgur mirror
Finally the skewing strength is defined in the blue "Multiply" node in the "Skew" frame.
To orient the cylinder differently you can just rotate the object at any angle rather then changing the maths of the node tree...

P.S.
Whoops, I just realized I didn't quite produce what you wanted. You wanted something more like this:

Imgur mirror

Imgur mirror
But actually a linear shift/skewing on the turn like this:

Imgur mirror

Imgur mirror

